# Playing Video In Android As An Intro (not working)

Tags: android, video, uri

The first screen you see when launching the app is a screen with just a video on it which acts as an intro and then it skips to the main menu.

For some reason the video won't actually play it juts says: sorry this video cannot be played.

Not sure if the videoView.start actually does anything here but tried with and without still same result.

Here is code for screen:

```
package com.narwars.www;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.VideoView;

public class FirstScreenVideo extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_first_screen_video);


    Button skipBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.skipBtn);

    skipBtn.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent launchMainMenu = new Intent (FirstScreenVideo.this, MainMenu.class);
            startActivity(launchMainMenu);

        }
    });
    String uriPath = "android.resource://com.narwars.www/raw/finalcut";
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(uriPath);
    VideoView videoView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.VideoView);
    videoView.setVideoURI(uri);
    videoView.start();

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.first_screen_video, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

Comment: IS anything being looged in logcat?

Comment: @Squonk sorry but emulator doesn't work on my pc so i export straight to phone should have made that clear...

Comment: Connect your phone to PC with a USB cable and use DDMS from the ANdroid SDK Tools to monitor the phone's logcat.

Comment: @Squonk thank you so much this has simplified my life 10 fold! I knew there was a way to connect phone but never researched it. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are missing a mediaController.
You try to do something like this:

```
import android.widget.MediaController; 
import android.widget.VideoView; 

VideoView sampleVideo = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.VideoView); 
sampleVideo.setMediaController(mc); 
Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.xxxxx.abc/" + R.raw.abc); 
sampleVideo.setVideoURI(uri); 
sampleVideo.start();
```

Comment: Do i need to declare the variable mc? if so how would i do this?